# .Net Core Multi-Platform underlying framework implementation

Tags: .net, .net-core

I've been using C# for around 1 year and a half now, and I get in touch with .NET core recently.
I know a major difference between .NET core & .NET is that - .NET core supports multi-platform, but I want to understand what's the underlying implementation for .NET core to support multi-platform.

Any good and easy-to-understand tutorials / online documents?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64262536/10696080 can answer it.

Answer (score 2):

Sherry,

The info is provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/about):

People commonly ask how .NET Core is implemented in order to support multiple operating systems. They typically ask if there are separate implementations or if conditional compilation is used. It's both, with a strong bias towards conditional compilation.